# How do I set up a database for a Sinatra app in Heroku?

Tags: ruby, git, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I made a Sinatra application that runs with a SQLite3 database. Everything runs smoothly on my local machine.

When I am deployed it to Heroku I had to change a few things, namely a Gemfile and a Procfile, while also changing my database code to this:

```
#Within a class

#Before
@DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://database.db')

#After
@DB = Sequel.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://localhost/db')
```

I changeed the database to Postgres, rather than SQLite3 because SQLite3 isn't supported with Heroku. (This may be where my problem stems from.)

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "1.9.3"

gem "sinatra"
gem "sequel"
gem "pg"
gem "postgres"
gem "json"
```

And my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec ruby main.rb -p $PORT
```

---

I made a git repository, and ran `heroku create`. I added all the files, committed and pushed them using git and I got my Heroku URL and everything is fine. I ran `heroku config` to check my URLs and got this result:

```
DATABASE_URL:postgres://uhyodailuzazve:hUSIuD_4MOYWmoiSGNZCPrQNyg@ec2-54-204-40-     140.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d1qkn1ivl7p013HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL:postgres://uhyodailuzazve:hUSIuD_4MOYWmoiSGNZCPrQNyg@ec2-54-204-40-140.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d1qkn1ivl7p013
```

(They are the same). Also my stack is "cedar"

```
=== enigmatic-taiga-5020 Available Stacks
bamboo-mri-1.9.2
bamboo-ree-1.8.7
* cedar
```

How can I have a database configured with Sinatra, going from Sequel to Postgres? I've looked at tutorials and they have gotten this far. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: You posted the PostgreSQL login and password for your Heroku database, you probably want to remove that and change the login/password.

Answer (score 1):

`@DB = Sequel.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])` should work fine, though in general you would assign the database to a constant, not an instance variable.